# Create an highlighter effect for highlighting specific region of an image or text loaded in Blender

Tags: image, effects

I see often this effect of virtually highlighting a text of a manuscript or report. I found a good tutorial using after effects https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0T3kcizcOY. I have tried to reproduce it using Blender, and importing the image as a plane. However, I can't find a modifier that helps me to achieve this effect, in my case also a simple change of brightness on the part of the text I am interested in could work. I was wondering if somebody had already faced this issue and could point me to the solution.

[image: Example of rendering of a dynamic highlighting of a text]

Comment: Hello, have you looked into Dynamic Paint?

Comment: @moonboots thanks a lot that seems very promising, I will study it in the next days